# Find an equation that models the path of a satellite if its path is a hyperbola

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find an equation that models the path of a satellite if its path is a hyperbola, a = 55,000 km, and c = 81,000 km. Assume that the center of the hyperbola is the origin and the transverse axis is horizontal.

My work: 
$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2 $$
$$55,000^2 + b^2 = 81,000^2 $$
$$b = 59464.27 $$
$$(\frac{x^2}{a^2}) - (\frac{y^2}{b^2}) = 1 $$
$$\frac{x^2}{55,000^2} - \frac{y^2}{59464^2} = 1 $$
$$\frac{x^2}{3,025,000,000} - \frac{y^2}{3,535,967,296} = 1$$

Did I do this correctly? If not, what did I do wrong?

Comment: What is $c$? ${}$

Comment: C is given as 81,000.

Comment: I am asking what is significance of $c$? As $a$ is half of transverse axis...What does $c$ mean?

Comment: C is the distance from the center to the focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly correct. Although there might be a bit estimation error here. You might want to take exact value of $b$. If it is an exam, you also might want to present your answer in same number of significant figures as in question.